# Using async data across different functions in Swift

Tags: json, swift, design-patterns

So I'm currently fetching some remote JSON data through an async call. By using a completion handler I'm able to use the data outside the call.

But now I'm wondering how I could process this data the right way.

For example I'm having different functions that rely on this data. Every time I need the data I could call it inside these functions. E.g.:

```
func generateRandomItem() {
    DataManager().requestData() { (result: [Model]) in
        //Generate Random item from the results of call here
    }
}


func listAlphabetically() {
    DataManager().requestData() { (result: [Model]) in
        //List all data alphabetically from the results of the call here
    }
}
```

But this approach will be wasting API calls I think since the data will only change once a week.

Another approach I was thinking about, was calling this function on launch of the application and store everything in a global var. This var can then be used in every single function whenever I need it. E.g.:

```
var allItems = [Model]()

func getAllItems() {
    DataManager().requestData() { (result: [Model]) in
        self.allItems = result
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this is that the data is only pulled in once, and never updated but only on app launch.

So this isn't much of a technical question but more a fundamental one. I'm pretty new to Swift and looking for the best design patterns. If my completion handler on the async call is also a wrong approach I would like to know how I could improve it!

Comment: You can make a global function to provide this JSON data. This function can return the cached data or decide that the cache is too old and need a fresh reload

Comment: Create a function to fetch data from the cloud. Then cache this data locally on the device (`Core Data` or some other `DB`). Let your UI always read from the local cache on the device. Every time app shows a screen which needs that data, pick from the local cache and in the background go and fetch the latest data from the cloud and update local cache. Once the local cache is updated then refetch from local UI. (Example: `NSFetchedResultsController` does help if you use `Core Data`)